# Facebook share button and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, refresh, share

I'm working on a website refreshing a div content with differents articles. I have to put a Facebook share button for each article.
The refreshing is done in Ajax with jQuery

What I do :
with the article.php page called, I send an ID value. The URL looks like that :

> http://www.website.org/index.php?page=article.php&id=892

In the index.php page, I've included :

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<script>
    // Facebook
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

In the article.php page,

```
<div id="fb_container" class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?PHP 
   $url = "http://www.website.org/index.php?page=article?id=".$id;
   echo $url; 
   ?>" data-type="button_count">
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('meta[property=og:title]').remove(); $('head').append('<?PHP echo $titre['contenu']; ?>');
    // Same for the others meta tags

    FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fb_container'));
});
</script>
```

The meta tags are updated, that's ok.
But the share button doesn't work :
- in the first load, it is visible but the shared page doesn't display the image and meta informations
- when we read another article, the share button isn't displayed

Any suggestion ?

Comment: You can not set OG meta tags via JS, the FB scraper doesn't care about JavaScript.

Comment: The first OG meta tags definition is not set dynamically, only when I load another article. The first values must be used, but here that doesn't work.
Howether, this is not the job of the FB.XFBML.parse function to parse the content after a dynamical change ?

Comment: Does `$(document).ready` execute when you load the code via AJAX? And how are you replacing the content - have you made sure the ID you are looking for is unique in the DOM, even after you dynamically load new stuff?

Comment: The $(document).ready is included in the article.php page loaded, the called page. For the unicity of the ID parameter, I've to check it that but I think there's no doubles.

Comment: Well, I've succeded to change dynalically the share button, but the meta og parameters are still not working. FB doen't see the changes.

Comment: Use the debug tool to update the cache. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've find a solution using an another ajax called page including the Facebook link and the FB.ui function :

in the index.php :

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'Your id app',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function openFbPopUp(fburl,fbimgurl,fbtitle,fbsummary) {
FB.ui(
          {
            method: 'feed',
            name: fbtitle,
            link: fburl,
            picture: fbimgurl,
            caption: fbtitle,
            description: fbsummary
          }
        );  
}
```

in the refreshed facebook.php page including the facebook share link :

```
// here the connection to the MySQL database
// read the values of the id element

<a onclick="openFbPopUp('<?PHP echo ($url_fb); ?>','<?PHP echo ("http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/".$photo['url_photo']); ?>','<?PHP echo ($titre['content']); ?>','<?PHP echo (substr(addslashes($description['content']),0,200)."..."); ?>')" value="SHARE">
<img src="images/fb-share.png">
</a>
```